# CSS3 card on 3d rotation still flickering - i've tried solutions with backface-visibility:hidden and translateZ with no success

Tags: jquery, html, css, transform

I have a picture gallery that is composed of polaroid-like pictures that are randomly "thrown" on the screen with different rotates and translates each. When I hover over an image, it scales x2, it comes to front with z-index and gets a rotation of "0".
Now here comes the problem: when you click the top-right of the pictures, it does a 3d card flip and on the back it has a comment section. However, the card flickers badly because of the background-color of the card div, and worse, when clicking the comment section, it "dissapers" behind the background color. This happens only in Chrome. I have tried different solutions, with translateZ(-1px) and changing backface-visibility of different divs, but it doesn't work. It only works if I remove the background color of the card, but everything besides the image becomes transparent and this, of course, is not what I want.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Tw3s/1/

**The flip's CSS**

```
.artGroup.flip {
    -webkit-perspective:800px;
    -moz-perspective:800px;
    -ms-perspective:800px;
    -o-perspective:800px;
    perspective:800px;
}
.artGroup.flip .artwork {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.artGroup.flip .detail, .artGroup.flip .theFlip {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg); 
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg); 
    -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg); 
    transform: rotateY(-180deg); 
}

.artGroup.flip img, .artGroup.flip .detail, .aaa, .bbb, .nota, .nrpoza{
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="theArt">
    <div class="artGroup slide">
      <div class="artwork">
          <img class="mare" src="http://api.ning.com/files/SgY6-Aw-QoVTrUyj0n7j9R5MHqRWf5ECVRbqLx7BTEScSgnO-ClKrLdK72nGe8X8koNM70oYq2kVtHH0RbauTHTfLqkLnEWi/13365705hJ600x400.jpg?width=600&height=400"/>
            <div class="nota"><b>Some description here.</b></div>
            <div class="nrpoza">55</div>
            <div class="aaa" style="position:absolute; display:block; left:520px; top:20px; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3); border-radius:37px; padding:7px;"><img class="mica" src="http://i.i.cbsi.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2011/03/16/Chrome-logo-2011-03-16.jpg"/></div>

        <div class="detail">
            <div class="bbb" style="position:absolute; display:block; left:520px; top:20px; background: rgba(211, 211, 211, .3); border-radius:37px; padding:7px; width:60px;"><img class="mica" src="http://i.i.cbsi.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2011/03/16/Chrome-logo-2011-03-16.jpg" style="width:60px"/></div>

           Some comment section here!!!

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And the Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        function NumarRandom(min, max) {
          return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
        }
        function NumarRandom(min, max) {
          return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
        }
        $('.artGroup').each(function(){
            $(this).css({ 
                '-webkit-transform':'rotate('+NumarRandom(-70,70)+'deg) scale(0.5)',
                '-moz-transform':'rotate('+NumarRandom(-70,70)+'deg) scale(0.5)',
                '-o-transform':'rotate('+NumarRandom(-70,70)+'deg) scale(0.5)',
                'transform':'rotate('+NumarRandom(-70,70)+'deg) scale(0.5)'
            });
            $(this).animate({'left':NumarRandom(000,100),'top':NumarRandom(0,100) });
            $(this).hover(
                function(){ $(this).css({'-webkit-transform':'rotate(0deg)', '-webkit-transform':'scale(1)'})},
                function(){ $(this).css({'-webkit-transform':'rotate('+NumarRandom(-80,80)+'deg) scale(0.5)'})}
            )
        });
    if ($('html').hasClass('csstransforms3d')) {    
            $('.artGroup').removeClass('slide').addClass('flip');

            $('.artGroup.flip .aaa').click(
                function () {
                    $(this).parent().addClass('theFlip');
                }
            );
            $('.artGroup.flip .bbb').click(
                function () {
                    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('theFlip');

                }
            );
        } else {
            $('.artGroup').hover(
                function () {
                    $(this).find('.detail').stop().animate({bottom:0}, 500, 'easeOutCubic');
                },
                function () {
                    $(this).find('.detail').stop().animate({bottom: ($(this).height() * -1) }, 500, 'easeOutCubic');            
                }
            );
        }
    });
```

Please help me with a solution for this, because I ran out of ideas.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: a fiddle would be very usefull

Comment: Hi Mihnea, I have added a fiddle. Sorry for the code if it's not structured too well, web design is just a passion for me so I don't have much experience. In the meantime I have tried on my local computer with adding some divs and alternating the background-color from transparent to white on flip. The results are better, but still I got flickering going on.

Comment: try this technique http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip . seems to work fine in all browsers .. and try not to keep styles inline (style="")